# How to access public subs of dynamically loaded user control in a panel

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, panel

I have a panel and a button in a form and 2 user controls, I dynamically loaded the first user control in the panel then inside the userControl1 I have a method that I want to access when I clicked the button in the form and then change the displayed user control to userControl2 in the panel, how should I do that?

form1 code:

```
Public Class form1

    Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
           Dim control1 = New UserControl1

           Panel1.Controls.Add(control1)
           control1.Location = New Point(0, 0)
           control1.Size = New Point(1351, 533)
    End Sub

End Class
```

UserControl1 Code:

```
Public Class UserControl1

    Public Sub doSomething()
           'Do something'
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Code added. I tried to simplified it since I think it would be much easier to understand it this way. What I want is to access that doSomething() at the click event of the button in the form and change the displayed user control to  UserControl2 in the panel.

Comment: You just need a reference to the control you created.  That code lets it go out of scope

Comment: can you please show how it is done? I'm fairly new when it comes with user-controls..

Comment: Will it always be a `UserControl1` at the time the button is clicked, or could it be one of multiple different controls?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll take as much as I can from your question and show you an example, there are many different ways you could do this, thus, may not answer your question 100% but will give you enough to get what you want.

I'm making an assumption that you only have one control1 and one control2.

My example will alternate, and access a sub routine in the active (shown) usercontrol on each click on the main form button.

In a module I would put:

```
Public control1 As New UserControl1
Public control2 As New UserControl2
```

In UserControl1 put:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    Me.BackColor = Color.Black
End Sub
```

In UserControl2 put:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    Me.BackColor = Color.White
End Sub
```

In your FormLoad event put:

```
    control1.Location = New Point(0, 0)
    control1.Size = New Point(1351, 533)
    Panel1.Controls.Add(control1)
```

In your Button1 click event put:

```
    Select Case Panel1.Contains(control1)
        Case True
            'Remove UserControl1 - Add UserControl2
            Panel1.Controls.Remove(control1)
            control2.Location = New Point(0, 0)
            control2.Size = New Point(1351, 533)
            Panel1.Controls.Add(control2)
            control2.DoSomething()
        Case False
            'Remove UserControl2 - Add UserControl1
            Panel1.Controls.Remove(control2)
            control1.Location = New Point(0, 0)
            control1.Size = New Point(1351, 533)
            Panel1.Controls.Add(control1)
            control1.DoSomething()
    End Select
```

The above is checking which UserControl is in the panel and alternating it and calling the 'DoSomething'. This is just an example to give you an idea. What you want may be different, you may have a button in your second UserControl and if so, amend the switch code to suit.

Comment: Thanks! the code seems to be working except the control2.DoSomething() and for the control1.DoSomething() too. It says " 'DoSomething' is not a member of UserControl2" even though I properly created the sub and the module.

Comment: Did you set them as 'Public'? Do you have the UserControls set as Public in the Module?

Comment: I do not know how to proceed.... I want to give you my project, or receive your project so we can compare. I don't know how to do that here.

Comment: Dim you put the UserControls declarations in a Module?

Comment: yes I put it at a module, it says " 'DoSomething' is not a member of UserControl2"

Comment: The only thing I can think of now is that there is something different you are doing. Check everything from my example to yours, especially things that refer to `control1/2` and `UserControl1/2`.